# Express.js app times out when attempting to query a PostgreSQL database

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, heroku

I've built an **Express.js** app, hosted by **Heroku**, with a non-embedded **PostgreSQL** database.

The app was running as intended until about a month ago, and for several months before that. However, when I logged in today, I ran into a serious problem.

**Whenever I try to access any page which queries the database, it tries to load for a few seconds, and then gives me the standard Heroku "Application Error" page.**

### Accessing the Database through Javascript

This is what a portion of my code that queries the database looks like:

```js
var that = this;
var title = "The Journal";
var queryString = "SELECT * FROM JournalEntry "+
                  "ORDER BY theTimeStamp ASC;";
var extract, data;
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});

console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
console.log("Hello!");

client.connect();

console.log("My!");

client.query(queryString, (err, result) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log("Lovely!");

    extract = result.rows;
    data = interpretJournalExtract(extract);
    data = objectifyExtract(data);
    client.end();
    that.finaliser.protoRender(req, res, "tabular",
                               { title: title, data: data });
});
```

And this is what the logs look like when I run this code:

```
2021-03-02T16:12:14.780345+00:00 app[web.1]: postgres://stfonefosxlmgt:227d3914dfb105c6ad3db47ad854f771391b15c8dead2da0a691a66d25cb2f65@ec2-54-228-237-40.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/de337svimlvbgo
2021-03-02T16:12:14.780701+00:00 app[web.1]: Hello!
2021-03-02T16:12:14.781269+00:00 app[web.1]: My!
2021-03-02T16:12:44.784363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/journal" host=hgmj.herokuapp.com request_id=f28bdda2-f3bd-40b2-a894-e07cb9e0054c fwd="86.191.159.122" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30012ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2021-03-02T16:12:44.785541+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /journal - - ms - -
```

You'll notice that the logs get to "Hello!" and "My!", but not to "Lovely!".

### Accessing the Database through the Heroku CLI

It's also worth noting that I ***can*** access the database through the Heroku CLI, and this is what my screen looks like when I do so:

```
-> Connecting to postgresql-curly-19296
psql (12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), server 11.11 (Ubuntu 11.11-1.pgdg16.04+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

hgmj::DATABASE=>
```

### The Bottom Line

**Why is this happening, and what can I do about it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem.
adding

`ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }`

parameter to connection worked. I needed to upgrade pg package for it to work.

Comment: 'I needed to upgrade pg package for it to work.' That was it!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your error code (503), and given that your code was working before, this means the PostgreSQL database is unavailable for some reason.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503

I would suggest checking your DATABASE_URL environment variable defined here:

```
const client = new Client({
connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
ssl: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into `process.env.DATABASE_URL` and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I've edited my question in the light of your suggestion. Note that the first line of the logs now contains a printout of the `process.env.DATABASE_URL` variable. I've also included details of how I'm currently able to access the DB through the Heroku CLI.

Comment: Do you get the same error when using ssl: true ? To isolate the error, try changing the client.connect() to client.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('connection error', err.stack)
  } else {
    console.log('connected')
  }
})

Comment: Yes, I get the same error with `ssl: true`; I only changed it to conform with [Heroku's updated guidlines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js). When I swap `client.connect()` with your code, **neither** of the two messages are present in the logs, which - I'm guessing now - means that it times out before an error is raised.

Comment: Hmm OK. You say you can connect with the heroku cli. Try running "heroku pg:credentials:url DATABASE" to print the connection string, and put that as your connectionString: in the client object

Comment: The connectionString is in the form postgresql://user:password@database.server.com:port/database
You can check this matches a console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL)

Comment: When I run `heroku pg:credentials:url DATABASE`, the last few lines of the output read: `Connection URL: postgres://stfonefosxlmgt:227d3914dfb105c6ad3db47ad854f771391b15c8dead2da0a691a66d25cb2f65@ec2-54-228-237-40.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/de337svimlvbgo`. Note that this matches the printout from calling `console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);` above. Sorry! I wish I had more helpful news...

Comment: This may be a simple timeout from overload as documented here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout. Try changing your query to var queryString = "SELECT * FROM JournalEntry LIMIT 10" see if that runs

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news once again, but the `LIMIT 10` hasn't solved anything. Indeed, the JournalEntry table only contains ~200 records - I checked just now with a `SELECT COUNT(*)` - so that was unlikely to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is connected to this issue https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2208. Try to reset yours database credentials. I have same problem, it doesn't fix it, but you can try.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful suggestion. Unfortunately, I've run `heroku pg:credentials:rotate` on my app, and it hasn't fixed the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with connecting to the database and in my case the solution was the addition of the parameter `require: true` to the `ssl` property. It looked like this for me:

```
const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: { require: true, rejectUnauthorized: false },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that hasn't done the trick either.